# Route maps in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, maps, error-messaging

I have just started working with R. I am trying to plot longitude-latitude data between 2 nodes on a map.

I have 4 columns of data (start longitude, start latitude; end longitude, end latitude)- all within USA.

I have used code from rstudio-pubs-static.

**Data:**

```
      slong    slat     elong    elat
1  -73.9440 40.6610 -122.2708 37.8044
2 -118.2500 34.0500 -117.8897 33.8361
3 -117.8897 33.8361 -118.2500 34.0500
```

**Code:**

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggrepel)

moveall <- read.csv("moveall.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
head(moveall,3)


usMap <- borders("state", colour="grey", fill="white")

ggplot() + usMap


allUSA <- ggplot() + usMap +
  geom_curve(data=moveall,
             aes(x=slong, y=slat, xend=elong, yend=elat),
             col="#00008b",
             size=.5,
             curvature=0.2) +
  geom_point(data=moveall,
             aes(x=slong, y=slat), 
             colour="blue",
             size=1.5) +
  geom_point(data=moveall,
             aes(x=elong, y=elat), 
             colour="blue") +
  theme(axis.line=element_blank(),
        axis.text.x=element_blank(),
        axis.text.y=element_blank(),
        axis.title.x=element_blank(),
        axis.title.y=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks=element_blank(),
        plot.title=element_text(hjust=0.5, size=12)) +
  ggtitle("Movement Map")

allUSA
```

**Error Message:** 'Discrete value supplied to continuous scale"

I have tried formatting the numbers but that has not worked.

Amy ideas/suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow! Your code is working for me, You probably have some problems in the data (seems like there are factors somewhere. Use `dput(moveall)` and paste here the results, we may help that way.

Comment: Many thanks. You are absolutely right. When I ran the 1st 1000 rows, the code worked, but all 6000 plus rows it is throwing an error. I will try to narrow it down. Many thanks again!

Comment: UPDATE: appears my .csv file was corrupt. Copy-pasting using the clipboard into a new dataframe eliminated the error.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: appears my .csv file was corrupt. Copy-pasting using the clipboard into a new dataframe eliminated the error